# How to tell apart a long "oh" and a long "oo"?

Tags: pronunciation, writing, phonetics, onomatopoeia

In [this comic](https://static1.fjcdn.com/comments/I+have+the+actual+comic+_fe0359a23736a2b1f68919f9dd123853.jpg) there's a long "ooooooh" at the end.

How can I tell if it's a long "oh" (*/o/*) or a long "oo" (*/uː/*)?

I thought it could be the 'h', but I don't think I've never seen "ooooooo" anywhere.

How does a native speaker read this sound effect, and how would you write a long "oh" and a long "oo"?

Comment: I read it as a long rising and falling oooOOOooo.

Answer (score 2):

Since neither "oooooh" nor "ohhhhh" are words that can be looked up in a dictionary, only a general rule of thumb can be given. That rule of thumb is that if there is more than one O, then it is [u:]. If there is only one O and one or more H's, then it is [o]. So in your example:

> ooooooh

It's [u:].

> ohhhhhh

This is [o].

If there are multiple O's *and* H's then it's [u:].

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a hard and fast rule for that. I guess it depends on context to some extent. The comic isn't particularly helpful in that regard. I don't know what the artist intended either.
Aside from the spelling suggested by the other answers here, there's a suggestion that "o" would be more to convey surprise or shock while "u" could convey disapproval or foreboding... But that's not absolute either. This is a little like asking how to pronounce something that is misspelled. Not necessarily a shortcoming of the reader but of the author/artist.